# which version of VM on Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Which version of VM should be used on Linux for Pharo/Seaside?
If I'm not mistaken, the one loaded by apt-get (and referenced in [seaside book](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/install-vm)) is Squeak VM.
Should this be preferred to Cog-VM? 
If yes, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of Seaside you may download a pre-compiled Pharo image from the [Seaside website](http://www.seaside.st/download/pharo) (they are called "One-Click experience") which is the easiest way to run the image. The VM distributed in the Seaside One-Click is a CogVM.

There are basically three VMs in the Squeak and Pharo world:

- StackVM: Implements optimized closures and context-to-stack mapping
- CogVM: StacVM + JIT (Just-In-Time compilation) + PIC (Polymorphic
  Inline Caches)
- CogVMMT: CogVM + Multi-threading

You may want to try checking the latest [CogVM for Linux](http://pharo.gforge.inria.fr/ci/vm/nbcog/linux/NBCog-linux-latest.zip) from the Pharo website too. The very latest are in the [developer's website](http://www.mirandabanda.org/files/Cog/VM/).

From my experience, I've found CogVMs are really faster than StackVM, although unstable for doing big data (reading and processing 2TB of CSV's) or debugging complex flows. That doesn't mean that you cannot run big data projects, but just **sometimes** could fail depending on how far are you going. On the other side, StackVMs are more mature and is the best place to learn how to modify the VM because the focus of CogVM is towards optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I feel I formulated my question poorly... I need to put a headless setup with Apache/lightHttpd as front end (so typical setup) and then stress test my application. Obviously I want it to be as fast as possible without being unstable, so it looks from your answer that Cog is the way to go (I always can revert to StackVM if it constantly fails)

Comment: Take a look at the Seaside book: http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/configure-apache and there blogs with some tips too: http://onsmalltalk.com/scaling-seaside-more-advanced-load-balancing-and-publishing

Comment: I use the latest CogVM for all my Seaside images and build processes. This VM has become extremely stable in the last years. I didn't see a single crash.

Comment: @Lukas: Thanks for commenting your experience, is really nice to hear that stability for web developements. Here are some crash dumps: http://pastebin.com/JLte3nRi of previous CogVM versions, although those kind of bugs are very rare as you said.

Comment: @Hernan: Strange, but your VM seems to be quite outdated (Nov 18, 2011). I regularly update to the latest VMs of Eliot: http://www.mirandabanda.org/files/Cog/VM/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, there is an easy to use PPA: http://www.pharo.org/pharo-download/ubuntu